# accusative after po

Tags: prepositions, accusative

"We each ate two cakes." = Ni manghis po du kukojn.
OR Ni manghis po du kukoj. ?

(Zamenhof: "Inter la esprimoj 'doni po 2 pecojn' kaj 'doni po 2 pecoj' estas ankoraŭ malfacile diri, kiu estas la pli bona, kaj tial ambaŭ esprimoj estas uzeblaj kaj bonaj".)

Edit: I didn't think to do a corpus search (many thanks to @das-g). Via [tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com), I've found quite a couple of instances of accusative use with po in *Kontakto*, *Le Monde diplomatique en Esperanto*, *La Ondo de Esperanto* and *Artikoloj el Monato*. Its use, when one must make such a choice, seems to prevail.

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zamenhof might have originally regarded *po* just as a normal preposition, and since it has nothing to do with a location, he applied the rule "nominative after a preposition unless accusative needed to show movement". Therefore we have

> *Por miaj kvar infanoj mi aĉetis dek du pomojn, kaj al ĉiu el la infanoj mi donis po tri pomoj.*
>
> -- [Ekzercaro de Fundamento, ekzerco 14](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/ekzercaro.html#ekzerco14)

But this created a problem because in the sentence

> *El ĉiuj rampaĵoj de la tero laŭ iliaj specoj, po paro el ĉiuj eniru kun vi.*
>
> -- Genezo 6 laŭ la traduko de L. Zamenhof

*po* cannot be a normal preposition since a prepositional phrase cannot be the subject of a clause in Esperanto. This might have sparked him to rethink about *po*, and use accusative after it when appropriate as in your example

- *Ni manĝis po du kukojn.*

Compare this with  *anstataŭ* and *kiel* which both can be followed by a main word in nominative or accusative depending on whether the phrase refers to the subject resp. object.

So we have the Fundamental use with nominative and what can be considered, the more logical use with accusative. This claim to being more logical is backed by the [analysis](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/nuanciloj.html#i-133) Wennergren does in PMEG, where he says that *po* is one of the *nuanciloj*, nuance markers, "nuancers". The key point in his analysis is that *po* always nuances a number and the following noun is the true main word, which is in nominative or accusative depending on the situation. Thus in

> *El ĉiuj rampaĵoj de la tero laŭ iliaj specoj, po paro el ĉiuj eniru kun vi.*

there is an omitted *unu* after *po*, and only the word *paro* is the subject. By this same logic the object of the action of eating is cakes in

- *Ni manĝis po du kukojn.*

and *po du* is just a *nuancilo*.

Answer (score 2):

Both

> Ni manĝis po du kukoj**n**.

and

> Ni manĝis po du kukoj.

**are correct and mean the same**: "We each ate two cakes." (or "We ate two cakes each.")

Which one you choose should depend on whether you regard *po* as a true preposition (and thus a true "rolmontrilo"; then don't accusative (*-n*) with it) or not (then do use accusative (*-n*) with it where appropriate, e.g. in direct objects such as here).

PMEG, a well-regarded grammar book about (and in) Esperanto treats this question in [this](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/nuanciloj.html) chapter:

> #### 23.6. Nuanciloj de nombraj kaj kvantaj vortoj
>
> ##### [Rolvortetoj kiel nuanciloj de nombro aŭ kvanto](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/nuanciloj.html#i-133)
>
> La rolvortetoj *ĉirkaŭ*, *de*, *ĝis*, *inter*, *sub*, *super* kaj ***po*** povas uziĝi kun nombraj aŭ kvantaj vortoj por ilin nuanci en diversaj manieroj[.]
>
> [...]
>
> En ĉi tiaj frazoj la rolvortetoj neniel koncernas eventualan postan O-vorton, sed havas sencon nur por la nombro. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Oni vidas, ke tiuj ĉi rolvortetoj ne montras frazrolon, kiam ili nuancas nombron aŭ kvanton. Ili ne estas rolmontriloj, sed havas ian E-vortecan rolon. [...]

It names these types of words "nuanciloj" and goes on:

> ##### [Nuanciloj kune kun veraj rolmontriloj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/nuanciloj.html#i-78r)
>
> Nombrovortaj nuanciloj povas aperi kune kun veraj rolmontriloj, kiuj montras la frazrolon de la tuta esprimo[.]
>
> [...]
>
> ##### [Neunueca uzo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/nuanciloj.html#i-3cn)
>
> Se oni opinias, ke tiaj ĉi nuanciloj ne estas rolmontriloj, tiam oni ja uzas N kaj aliajn rolmontrilojn kune kun ili, kiam tio estas bezonata. [...] Sed se oni tamen opinias, ke ili estas veraj rolmontriloj, tiam oni neniam uzas la finaĵon N kune kun ili, kaj ankaŭ forlasas diversajn aliajn rolmontrilojn.
>
> **Zamenhof hezitis pri la afero.** Li iafoje uzis tiajn ĉi nuancilojn kiel verajn rolmontrilojn forlasante la finaĵon N ekz. ĉe objektoj. Alifoje li uzis ilin laŭ la ĉi-antaŭaj klarigoj. La nuancilon *ĉirkaŭ* li uzis en ambaŭ manieroj. **La nuancilon *po* li uzis normale nur kiel rolmontrilon, sed li skribis, ke ankaŭ uzado kun N estas bona ([Lingvaj Respondoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/aldonoj/literaturo.html#lingvaj-respondoj) p. 70, [n-ro 79](https://tekstaro.com/t?nomo=lingvaj-respondoj#lingvaj-respondoj-resp-79)). Li eĉ mem uzis *po* en tia maniero almenaŭ unu fojon.** La aliajn nuancilojn Zamenhof uzis tiel malofte, ke estas malfacile diri, kiajn regulojn li sekvis. Unueca principo por ĉiuj ĉi nuanciloj ne estas do trovebla ĉe Zamenhof[.]
>
> [...]
>
> Nuntempe oni kutime uzas ĉiujn ĉi vortetojn nur kiel nuancilojn en tiaj esprimoj, do ne kiel rolmontrilojn – **escepte de *po*. Pri *po* la lingvouzo varias. Iuj sekvas la Zamenhofan (kaj Fundamentan) modelon, aliaj sekvas la samajn regulojn kiel por ekz. *ĉirkaŭ*.**
>
> ##### [Konkludo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/nuanciloj.html#i-ueo)
>
> [...]
>
> **Pri *po* oni tamen povas agi laŭplaĉe.** Pro la Zamenhofa kaj Fundamenta uzo restas ĉiam regule uzi *po* kiel rolmontrilon de la posta esprimo. Oni do povas ĉiam forlasi N post *po*. Tio iafoje povas esti konfuzokrea (ekz. kiam mankas N-finaĵo ĉe objekto). Alifoje tio estas eleganta. Oni povas ankaŭ ĉiam uzi *po* kiel nuran nuancilon almetante ĉiam la bezonatajn rolmontrilojn. Tio estas tre klara, sed iafoje povas esti iom peza. **Apenaŭ havas sencon disputi pri tio, kiu el la du uzoj estas preferinda. Praktike ambaŭ bone funkcias.**
>
> [...]

So according to PMEG, language use hasn't (yet?) settled on whether or not to use accusative (*-n* ending) after *po* in direct objects **and** Zamenhof said either is OK (though he seems to have preferred the nominative<sup>1</sup>) so **you should thus feel free to choose whichever feels more right to you**.

<sup>1</sup> You quote Zamenhof with:

> Inter la esprimoj 'doni po 2 pecojn' kaj 'doni po 2 pecoj' estas ankoraŭ malfacile diri, kiu estas la pli bona, kaj tial ambaŭ esprimoj estas uzeblaj kaj bonaj

However, the [full answer](https://tekstaro.com/t?nomo=lingvaj-respondoj#lingvaj-respondoj-resp-79) he gave is a bit longer:

> ##### Pri la kazo post “po”
>
> Inter la esprimoj “doni po 2 pecojn” kaj “doni po 2 pecoj” estas ankoraŭ malfacile diri, kiu estas la pli bona, kaj tial ambaŭ esprimoj estas uzeblaj kaj bonaj. Tamen konsiderante, ke danke la intervenon de la vorto “po” la “pecoj” jam ne dependas rekte de la “doni”, **ni konsilas uzi post “po” (tiel same kiel post “da”) la nominativon (“doni po 2 pecoj”)**. Alia kaŭzo por tiu ĉi konsilo estas ankaŭ la cirkonstanco, ke laŭ nia opinio “ĉie, kie oni dubas inter la nominativo kaj akuzativo, oni devas uzi la nominativon”.

(strong emphasis (**bold**) in all above quotations mine)

Comment: which style is preferred / more common among experienced Esperantists?

Comment: I don't know which style is preferred / more common among experienced Esperantists, @Sabrina. Maybe an analysis of https://tekstaro.com/ could answer that, but it'd be tricky, as one would have to distinguish cases where _po_ is used to introduce a direct object (and thus could be followed by accusative) from others (e.g. in combination with other prepositions) which require nominative.

Comment: What also plays a role in selecting the "preferred" way, is that some Esperantists strongly favour what Zamenhof said, while others permit at least some evolution and  even a reinterpretation, what is what Wennergren essentially has done by introducing the concept of _nuanciloj_. My two cents' advise is that whichever standpoint you take, be at least consequent in your text. That is, if without "n" when an object, never have "po" as a part of the subject (see the Genesis citation), and vice versa, if a part of a subject, do not forget "n" when in an object.